# Topology on fundamental group so that its a topological group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $(X,x_0)$ be a pointed topological space.Let $ \pi _1(X,x_0)$ denote the fundamental group of $X$ based at $x_0$.What are 'good' topologies one can put on $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ so that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is a topological group?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26680/fundamental-group-as-topological-group